# Saving ArrayList in Activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin, arraylist

I have been trying for a couple of days to find a way to do this.

I am building a food ordering app and I have 3 activities, one for ordering, one for showing the order confirmation and one for displaying all the orders. Everything works except I cannot display the orders, only the last one.

I have tried `sharedPreferences`, intent Bundles in all kinds of ways but cannot figure it out.

I think the problem is that every time I go back to the activity, the `ArrayList` variable that contains the orders is reinitialized and only shows the latest order.

I would like to be able to show all the orders that have been placed while the app was on.

Any tips?

Here is the code for my Orders activity so you can see what I have tried:

```
public class AllaBestallningar extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> minaOrders = new ArrayList<>();

private static final String TEXT_CONTENTS = "AllaOrders";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alla_bestallningar);

        SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("orders", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String order = sp.getString("order", "ingen text");
        minaOrders.add(order);
        minaOrders.add("Estelle");
        minaOrders.add("Nicklas");

        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, minaOrders);

        ListView ordersList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.minList);

        ordersList.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.app_meny, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.laggBesMeny:
                Intent i = new Intent(AllaBestallningar.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            case R.id.minaBesMeny:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Du är redan på beställningsidan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        outState.putStringArrayList(TEXT_CONTENTS, minaOrders);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        minaOrders = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList(TEXT_CONTENTS);
    }
}
```

This is the main Activity:

```
package learnprogramming.academy.cafestudent;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.nio.channels.InterruptedByTimeoutException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button buttonPizza, buttonSallad, buttonKyckling, buttonRak;
    String bestallning = "", option= " ";
    Double pris = 0.0;
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    RadioButton radioButton;
    SharedPreferences sp;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonPizza = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPizza);
        buttonSallad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSallad);
        buttonKyckling = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonKycklingmacka);
        buttonRak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRakmacka);

        OnClickListener onOrder = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v == buttonPizza) {
                    bestallning = bestallning + "Pizza 25kr \n";
                    pris += 25.00;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tillagd i beställningen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (v == buttonSallad) {
                    bestallning = bestallning + "Sallad 45kr \n";
                    pris += 45.00;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tillagd i beställningen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (v == buttonKyckling) {
                    bestallning = bestallning + "Kycklingmacka 40kr \n";
                    pris += 40.00;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tillagd i beställningen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (v == buttonRak) {
                    bestallning = bestallning + "Räkmacka 40kr \n";
                    pris += 40.00;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tillagd i beställningen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                option = "\n " + bestallning + pris.toString()+ "kr \n ---------";
            }
        };

        option = "\n " + bestallning + pris.toString()+ "kr \n ---------";

        sp = getSharedPreferences("orders", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        buttonPizza.setOnClickListener(onOrder);
        buttonSallad.setOnClickListener(onOrder);
        buttonKyckling.setOnClickListener(onOrder);
        buttonRak.setOnClickListener(onOrder);


        Button bestalla;
        bestalla = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBestall);

        View.OnClickListener onPlaceOrder = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(bestallning == ""){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Du har inte gjort några val", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                        editor.putString("order", option);
                        editor.commit();

                        Intent place = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Bestallningar.class);
                        Bundle bestall = new Bundle();
                        bestall.putString("beställning", bestallning);
                        bestall.putDouble("pris", pris);
                        place.putExtras(bestall);
                        startActivity(place);

                        bestallning = "";
                        pris = 0.0;
                    }
                }

            }
        };

        bestalla.setOnClickListener(onPlaceOrder);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.app_meny, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.laggBesMeny:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Du är redan på beställningsidan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.minaBesMeny:
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AllaBestallningar.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void checkButton(View v) {
        int radioId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton = findViewById(radioId);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Du har valt leverans kl: " + radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see where you're writing to the shared preferences anywhere.

Comment: Hello, the shared Preference is in the MainActivity, this is the Activity showing all the orders.

Answer (score 0):

The orders should be stored using the Repository pattern.
A repository is an object that has a single instance that is accessible from any screen in the application and whose lifecycle is not tied to any activity.

This is just a pattern, there is no library or class to implement, you'll have to Google "repository pattern" to learn how to implement it.

The repository will have methods for retrieving and storing data. Internally it can then use a database to persist the data between sessions, or just store it in a variable in memory if you don't need to persist it. It can also make network calls if you need to fetch data and then store it in the database, etc.